# Is it feasible to get all the components under one class, make them static and reference them from all other scripts? (Using C# with Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity3D with c#, how feasible would it be to put all the components under one class, make them static, and reference them from all other scripts?

So that if changes have to be made to the game objects they are done in one script. All other scripts access the game objects they need with all bools, variables, etc. on each object by first referencing this class? Has anyone done this? What are the pros and cons? Would it increase or decrease productivity/game speed?

Comment: I think your overthinking it, at a guess I suspect your using visual studio so just refactor(rename with checks) the class/component names and they will be changed throughout your project.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want some kind of let's name it `MainController` which simply holds references to all other components related to that object somehow similar to an interface, right? I'ld say: Yeah why not? I often do this for not having to use `GetComponent`, `GetComponentInChildren` etc on the fly but let the `MainController` already collect all references on `Awake` e.g.

Comment: derHugo, this is what I was looking at. This is more an opinion based question. I wanted to see whether this is a feasible approach. Thanks for the confirmation. I wanted to avoid adding the reference in the Inspector and acquire all references from code in ONE SCRIPT. Thanks.